# Merge gig tag into concert

Tags: discussion, tags

All current questions tagged [gig](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gig) are also tagged [concert](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concert). We could just remove all uses of "gig", but I suspect that it would be nicer for it to stay as a synonym for counties, cultures, or sub-cultures where that's the normal term.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting... I see "gig" as being any form of job, not specifically concert. For example, a common usage might be "I got a gig shooting this new clothing line." So, from that perspective, they don't seem like they *should* be the same tag.

Comment: Good point. From a musician's point of view the gig is music — from a photographer's, it's different.  I'm just going to remove it from there questions.

Comment: @mattdm - cool. Maybe we should update the tag wiki. If you want to, great, otherwise I'll get it when I get out of my meeting.

Comment: I agree, gig is more of a job, where as concert is a specific type of event. I think the two should remain conceptually separate, despite current usage patterns.

Comment: Regional differences in usage apply here. In the Southeast U.S., a "gig" is almost always about music or the broader performing arts (dance, theater, etc.). Photographers usually refer to a job as a "shoot".

Comment: @MichaelClark - I've heard both up here, it's all over the map. I think, oddly enough, a gig might encompass concert, but concert does not encompass gig.

Answer (score 0):

Gig is what those being paid to be there call it. Concert is what those who are paying to be there (or at the very least not being paid to be there) call it. Use of gig beyond a musical setting or another form of performance art varies from location to location but in the U.S. it almost always seems specific to the performing arts in my experience.

Comment: At least in the UK, "gig" is pretty much synonymous with "pop music concert" - and perhaps more common. But that doesn't mean we can't keep them separate as gig clearly does have another meaning as well.

Comment: Most of the photo pros I know in my neck of the woods call it a "shoot". Some of the photojournalists call it an "assignment". Regional differences.

Comment: A *shoot* is normally something over which the photographer (and, often, art directors and stylists) have a degree of control. An *assignment* tends to be exactly that, something done at the behest of an editor by a staff photographer or stringer. *Gig* is a much more general term covering both and more. And yes, you can have a gig shooting someone else's gig.

Comment: Stan, It really depends on regional usage. I know guys, some of whom regularly push their work over the AP or Getty Sports, that refer to a college football game as "I've got to go to a shoot today." or "I'm doing a shoot today."